# Cannot access GAL on Exchange 2010 from new accounts

Tags: exchange-2010, outlook-2010

I have a problem at one of my clients. They have an internal Exchange 2010 server setup with about 20 mailboxes (plus AD, DNS, DHCP, the works).

Since we started supporting them, we created around 4 new AD accounts and mailboxes. None of those new accounts can see the Global Address List, they get an error stating there's no connection to the Exchange server.

When first configuring Outlook for one of these new accounts, the details get automatically populated, but the account cannot verify with the Exchange server. They use 1 server for Outlook Web Access and CAS and another one for the mailboxes themselves. say web.domain.com for OWA and exc.domain.com for Exchange server.

When the account details populates the New Mailbox dialog in Outlook, the default server populated is web.domain.com, but the account fails to verify. It has to be manually set to exc.domain.com, at which point the account gets verified, but the server changes back to web.domain.com.

Also, when any of these new accounts are set in Outlook to operate without Cache Mode, they automatically go into "Working Offline" and we haven't managed to connect the accounts. They can only send and receive emails / tasks, etc... when in Cache Mode, but in that case, the GAL doesn't work, nor we are able to connect other mailboxes to their Outlook like room mailboxes.

Also, when they get assigned tasks, they receive the notification but cannot delete, approve, reject or update them from their inbox.

We have verified that the older users are perfectly OK and also tried to figure out in which way these new accounts differ from the old ones, but the only difference we could find was the fact that some (and only some) of the old accounts have Archiving activated, but that's about as far as we got.

We would appreciate any help possible or even a hint towards the right direction. Maybe a way to compare an old account to the new to see where's the difference.

Answer (score 1):

I would start with inspecting the logs on both Exchange servers, then would continue to validate the server who responsible for creating OAB. This OAB is generated based on the policy that usually includes all the objects with Exchange attributes. Second, validate the properties of the database where the user's mailbox located and last make sure that the settings defined at the HUB access section of the EMC are properly populated with the correct server names and that the client computers are properly see them.